# How to retrieve nodejs session value in the rendering html page?

Tags: html, node.js, session

I need to access this username in registration page. The following code is not working. Can you suggest what need to be done?

```
  app.post('/login', function (req, res) {
    if(req.body.username === "ms" || req.body.password === "ms") {
     sess=req.session;
     req.session.password = req.body.password;
     req.session.username = req.body.username;      
     res.render('/registration.html', { username:req.user.username });
  }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use template engine like [pug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pug) .

With this method, you will be able to send JSON data, and render a view

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. can you suggest some way in html?